# After update to Sonarqube 6.4 java code coverage exclusion does not work

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube6.3

We have added one property in our maven project to exclude few of the java project from sonar coverage

```
<properties>
   <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>
```

which was working fine in `Sonarqube 6.3`.

After upgrading to `Sonarqube 6.4` we found this project are not excluding from sonar coverage.

Is this anissue in the `Sonarqube 6.4`? Do we have any work around for this.

Comment: why do you not exclude them in the jacoco report or do not provide the jacoco report for those projects?

Comment: Thanks  Simon Schrottner for your prompt response..now i will try with your approach..but if this is an issue sonarqube has to fix this

Comment: Well, i highly question your motivation. Basically right now you pass on data which you do not need, which sonar should compute to totally ignore - does not sound like an efficient way of resource handling to me - maybe it is a bug, but I would rather investigate in this case into your own process

Comment: Thanks Simon Schrottner (+1)